# How to add quotations to words in an array to treat them like strings

Tags: ruby, excel

In excel, I have a list of city names in a single cell that are comma delimited like this:

```
Melrose, Mott Haven, Port Morris, Hunts Point, Longwood, Claremont, Concourse Village,
Crotona Park, Morrisania, Concourse, High Bridge, Fordham, Morris Heights, Mount Hope,
etc.
```

What I want to do is use them as an array in Ruby. However, without quotations around each city name, Ruby will not treat each city name as a string and thinks they are method names. I don't know how to do a function in excel that iterates through each word (since they are all in the same cell) and adds quotes around them, so is there a way to do this in pure Ruby?

I want something like this:

```
"Melrose", "Mott Haven", etc....
```

Just to clarify: I have the data in excel with all the words separated by commas in a single cell and was just wondering about a way to use Ruby to interate through each word to add quotes around each word.

Comment: Your question is misleading if not confusing. Are you receiving this as bare form as is (which I cannot imagine that it is possible), or is this a Ruby array with some mysterious objects in it (which I also cannot imagine how it is possible), or is this a single string? Do you want to do this in Excel or in Ruby? Do you want to add quotations around each word (which would be expressed as e.g., `"\"Melrose\""`)?

Comment: Are you describing what actually happens as a result of reading an Excel file in a Ruby program? Because that doesn't sound right. It should treat cell values as strings. Can you post the code that results in that list you described?

Comment: Just an update - I decided to just use string functions within Excel after I used 'text to columns' to split the values delimited by commas. Thanks for all the input here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"Melrose, Mott Haven, Port Morris, Hunts Point, Longwood".split(", ")
```

Comment: Explain *why* this works. It's better to teach people to fish, not give them fish. Plus, this will break if there is ever a comma NOT followed by a space.